# com.xxx.xxx W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

Am trying to load Interstitial Ad on click of a button. unfortunately, getting this.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzjl@f5ae32b
> at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1757)

**app build.gradle**

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0'
implementation 'io.github.kobakei:ratethisapp:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
```

**project build.gradle**

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use the Firebase BoM, you should set it set the versions of all Firebase dependencies.  Your are not letting it the version of this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0'
```

In fact, you shouldn't need firebase-core at all any more.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries):

> The Firebase Android library firebase-core is no longer needed. This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.

So, just remove the dependency entirely if you aren't using it directly.  Or at least remove the version number.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use analytics, try remove this line:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```